# Able to update data even if user is logged out in another tab React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logging, redux, signing

I am able to update data even if a user is logged out.
Suppose I am logged in from 1 tab and have an update address component which I have opened in another tab. After I logged out from the first tab and then after I 1 render the other component gets to the login page. It is fine until here but, suppose in the other tab I have very details filled and just clicking send button is left. If I log out from the first tab and click send in 2nd tab I will be redirected to the login page but the address will get updated. I want to fix this. I don't want to update if a user is logged out.

The button function is here:

```
 const handleUpdateEmail = async () => {
        let response = await UserService.supportUpdateUserAttributes({
            email: emailToSearch,
            newEmail: newEmail
        });

        if (response.isSuccesfully) {
            setIsSuccess(true);
            setMessage('Successfully updated the email to: ' + newEmail);
            setEmailToSearch(newEmail);
            console.log('Successfully updated the email to: ' + newEmail);
        } else {
            setIsSuccess(false);
            setMessage("Couldn't update email. Error: " + (response.error || 'Unknown error occurred.'));
            console.log("Couldn't update email. Error: " + (response.error || 'Unknown error occurred.'));
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share more code for the component or repo.

Any way one solution could be that use isLoggedIn state which when user logs out set it to false and, when calling API, Check the state to see if user is logged in. That way if user is not logged in he cannot call the method.